# Rotated NSString dimensions

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, appkit

We've got a NSString that we measure the bounding box of using `- (NSSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes`. All good.

Now we're rotating that string using standard `NSAffineTransform` rotate operations - as it seems to be the only way to draw rotated NSStrings (?).

However, now the bounding box is rotated as well and we're getting the bounds of the unrotated text using `sizeWithAttributes:`.

Is there a straight-forward way to get the bounding box (or dimensions) of the rotated text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `CGRect` from your string's bounds and use `CGRectApplyAffineTransform` to get the transformed rect. It will be the smallest axis-aligned rect that contains the rotated string.

Comment: CGRectApplyAffineTransform()!  I just love Quartz/Cocoa :-)  Cheers